# Why there are no easily available implementation of database for high dimensional data (>100dimensions)?

Tags: database, dimensions

Why there are no easily available implementation of PostGIS-like database for high dimensional data (>100dimensions) that allows for fast region based query? If there is, can anyone recommend?

Comment: Postgres with [MADlib](http://madlib.apache.org/product.html)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - this doesnt do region query, like return all points within x distance from y